# Running an executable whose parameter values are specified as variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, build

I am writing a release script in powershell and need to invoke a custom executable and pass in a bunch of parameters to the executable. Few of these parameters are assigned values from various conditions and executions in the script. I see that the values are not getting evaluated when the executable is invoked. Some of the variables need to be passed in as a series of arguments inside double quotes as well. Shown below is a smaple call

mysample.exe '-forcerebuild' '-release=**$CALC_VERSION**' '-projfile=sample.proj' '-buildoptions="/p:AllowDevDependencies=true /p:AssemblyVersion=**$CALC_ASSEMBLY_VERSION** /flp:LogFile=**$env:temp**\build.log /p:BaseIntermediateOutputPath=**$PROJECT_BASE**\build\ /clp:nosummary"'

All the variables that need to be evaluated are highlighted. The exe expects all the options provided to -buildoptions inside quoted **-buildoptions="all build options"**

The values don't seem to get evaluated. However, if i put build options as a separate variable and print it, the values seem to get evaluated. I am new to powershell and would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that powershell doesn't do variable expansion inside single quoted strings. For example:

```
$test_variable = "test"
write-host "this is a $test_variable"
write-host 'this is a $test_variable'
```

will print

```
this is a test
this is a $test_variable
```

Also, powershell has problems in passing arguments to exes. There is a util called `EchoArgs.exe` that comes with [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/). Use that and pass your argument to that to see if they are passed fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the single-quotes as you said and the variables are getting evaluated. The EchoArgs.exe tool is really cool, i could see all the arguments and the values being passed. Now, i see that all the options inside -buildoptions="all build options" are getting evaluated as individual arguments. How do i retain the double=quotes and still get the values to evaluate?

Comment: @praskris - You have to do something like `"\`"$test_variable\`""`